# Using Selenium to enter text into Rich Text editor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, richtextbox

Here is a screen shot

[RichTextEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1kjX.png)

What is the best way to use Selenium C# to enter text into this text box?

Comment: Regular expressions is a good option.

Comment: I would go with sendkeys! :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is, when your input field has an Id.

then you just go:

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("Your Id")).SendKeys("Your Text);
```

Your editor got an id. Maybe it will work with his id. If not
and you are not able to edit the site and you are sure, that the site won't be edit anymore you can use XPath. A Plugin for Firefox (Selenium IDE) generates  XPath code automatically for you.

[check it out here.](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)

Otherwise use the class.
Maybe this code will work:

```
driver.findElement(By.ClassName("ql-editor)).sendKeys("Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Target your SendKeys to the div element of that richtext that has attribute contenteditable='true'